# Use internationalization I10n in a SonarQube 6.3.1 custom plugin

Tags: java, plugins, sonarqube

Would somebody have an example of how to properly use `internationalization (I10n)` in a `SonarQube 6.3.1` plugin, in both Java and JavaScript parts? For example how to use these values in the code.

Thanks for all.

Comment: Have you read https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Internationalization ? Then you can have a look on this sample plugin : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example/tree/master/src/main/resources/org/sonar/l10n/example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample plugin : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example, where i10n files can be found here : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example/tree/master/src/main/resources/org/sonar/l10n/example